# How to debug a SQL query that results in an error "Incorrect syntax near 'for'"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

```
alter table tbl_Donor
add constriant df_con1
default ((1)) for Active;
```

I'm getting error stating that:

> Incorrect syntax near 'for'.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Different syntax here...

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Please, try to find a title that describes the problem!

Comment: Please go read [ask], and pay attention to (not only) what it says about question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
alter table tbl_Donor
add constraint df_con1
default 1 for Active;
```

Answer (score 1):

You misspelled constraint.

In sql-server:

```
alter table t add constraint df_con1 default 1 for Active;
```

Answer (score 0):

For adding default constraint:-

MySQL:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Donor
ALTER Active SET DEFAULT 1;
```

SQL Server / MS Access:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Donor
ALTER COLUMN Active SET DEFAULT 1;
```

Oracle:-

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_Donor
MODIFY Active DEFAULT 1;
```

Comment: it didn't work either i m using sql management studio its showing error in all the three statement

Comment: Use second statement only `ALTER TABLE tbl_Donor
ALTER COLUMN Active SET DEFAULT 1;` and if there is an error, type it.